# Random null chars in read() function

Tags: c, sockets

I am building a basic client and server in TCP.  it's working except when the key gets kinda large.  It just sends back and forth keys until the end of time.  When it gets bigger (aka 4096) the read() statement will randomly get a null and then break the key into two msgs which then breaks the cycle.

I'm really not sure why it's doing this, the server code is working as it has been tested with other clients, so something is wrong with my client.  Any ideas (it's pretty short):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 5120

// Error message taken from reference
void error(const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit(0);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portNumber, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    // Invalid arguments
    if (argc < 4)
        exit(0);
    else if (atoi(argv[3]) < 1 || atoi(argv[3]) > 4096)
        exit(0);

    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
    char buffer2[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    bzero(buffer2, BUFFER_LENGTH);
    strcpy(buffer2, "Connect.  Key length:  ");
    strcpy(buffer, strcat(buffer2, argv[3]));
    portNumber = atoi(argv[2]); // Get port number in int format
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create socket connection to server using internet constants

    // Did we open the socket succesfully?
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("Error opening socket.");

    // Is the IP Address valid?
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL)
        error("Could not connect to server. Terminating.");

    // Initialize to zero and then set
    // Taken from reference
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("Could not connect to server. Terminating.");

    short connected = 1;
    do 
    {
        // Send initial request on first pass
        // Afterwards send the resposne we were given
        printf("Sending: %s\n", buffer);
        printf("Length of msg: %d\n", (strlen(buffer) + 1));
        n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
        if (n < 1) 
             error("Failed to send Message. Terminating.");

        // Get session key response
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
        n = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
        if (n < 1)
            error("Could not fetch result.  Terminating.");

        // Stop
        if (strcmp(buffer, "Invalid session key.  Terminating.") == 0)
            break;

        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        sleep(1);
    } while (connected == 1);

    // Done (this should never be reached in this client)
    error("Could not fetch result.  Terminating.");
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should I be able to tell what the server is sending?  Is it expected to be a valid string?  (no NULLs in the middle)

Comment: The server is expected to respond with "Session key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" (where X is random chars up to 4096 of them)

Comment: And the result of `read()` tells you how many characters it read. @altendky: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant; it's incorrect to use it to refer to the null character/byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `strcpy()`, or any `str*()` function, on binary data. You're not dealing with strings. Use `memcpy()` and specify the number of bytes you want to copy.

The `str*()` functions operate on *strings*; a string is defined by the C standard as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". But in binary data, a null character (zero byte) is just another chunk of data that doesn't necessarily have any significance.

If your binary data looks like this (in hex):

```
4b d9 e7 b3 00 96 89 fb
```

then `strcpy()` will ignore everything after the `00` byte.  Worse, if your binary data looks like:

```
4b d9 e7 b3 2f 96 89 fb
```

with *no* null bytes, then `strcpy()`, or `strlen()`, or any string function will continue past the end of your buffer, with unpredictable results.

Comment: The `strlen()` call specifying the length to write seems like the one that would actually be problematic.

Comment: Errrr, i seem to have no issues until I get into the while loop, then anywhere from 2 to X number of calls will continue until it randomly crashes by not receiving the whole msg because of the null character.  It seems to work for 2048 and under, so i was thinking at one point it's a buffer issue, but that didn't seem to be the case

Comment: You're using string functions on a buffer that may not contain any null characters -- and if it does, they don't mark the logical end of your data. Use the `mem*()` functions, *not* the `str*()` functions.

Comment: The first two printf statements in the while loop were debug statements for myself, and the only str*() function i am using in the while loop is strcmp() (which is working as its supposed to), the read() function will randomly only receive part of the msg from the server and then read the second half in the next passnig of the loop.

Comment: `n = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);` reads binary data into `buffer`; `n` tells you how many bytes it read. `strcmp(buffer, "Invalid session key.  Terminating.")` treats the contents of `buffer` as a zero-terminated string. It work, appear to work, or fail catastrophically depending on the actual contents of `buffer`. By applying any `str*()` function to `buffer`, you're *promising* that it contains a zero-terminated string, and that anything past the zero terminator is irrelevant.

Comment: it is a zero terminated string, the random key only uses alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Is there something that I am missing that guarantees that the entire 4096+ bytes are there prior to calling `read()`?  Or that `read()` will wait for as many bytes as are requested?

Comment: hmmm...it seems to be working on localhost but its not working across the internet.  I feel like the graders of my project will be doing this on a local network.

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue...  but if all you want is a grade, then perhaps you are right and the graders won't bother to check for a basic error like not allowing time for data to transfer.  Timeouts are key to any sort of communication.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the data sent by one `write()` is read by exactly one `read()`. There is nothing in TCP or the Sockets API specification that supports this assumption. You have to read until you get an entire message, and 'message' is defined by you, not by TCP or the API.

Answer (score -1):

For debugging purposes only, perhaps a `sleep()` would be helpful between the `write()` and `read()` so as to give the server time to respond?  Configuring appropriate timeouts would be the correct way to handle it in the long term.  Then again, I may be on totally the wrong track.

Comment: Sleeps *never* help in network programming. The `read()` will block until data is received. Sleeps are just literally a waste of time.

Comment: Agreed, `sleep()` was distinctly the wrong thing to do, though useful for debugging a timing issue.  Is `read()` guaranteed to read the specified number of bytes?  Or just to block until it has read something?  Somehow I am not finding a clear reference for this.